# Python filter with multiple conditions for string and date columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, where-clause

have a CSV dataset and I need to filter it with conditions but the problem is that the condition can be true for multiple days. What I want is to keep the last true value for these conditions within 3 days.

My dataset looks like this

```
Date           City             Summary              Flight No.    Company
2-18-2019       NY            Airplane land              23         Delta 
2-18-2019     London          Cargo handling              4         British
2-18-2019      Dubai          Airplane land              92         Emirates
2-19-2019      Dubai          Airplane stay              92         Emirates
2-19-2019      Paris          Flight canceled            78         British
2-19-2019       LA            Airplane Land              7          United
2-20-2019      Dubai          Airplane land              92         Emirates
2-20-2019       LA            Airplane land              29         Delta
2-20-2019       NY            Airplane left              23         Delta
2-21-2019      Paris          Airplane reschedule        78         British
2-21-2019      London         Airplane land              4          British
2-21-2019       LA            Airplane from NY land      29         Delta
~~~
3-10-2019      London         Airplane land              4          British
3-10-2019      Paris          Airplane Land              78       Air France
3-10-2019       LA            Reschedule                 29         United
3-11-2019       NY            Cargo handled              23         Delta
3-11-2019      Dubai          Arrived be4 2 days         34         Etihad
~~~
3-21-2019      Dubai          Airplane land              92         Etihad
3-21-2019     New Delhi       Reschedule                 9          AirAsia
3-21-2019      London         Cargo handling             5         Lufthansa
3-22-2019     New Delhi       Airplane Land              9          AirAsia
3-22-2019       NY            Reschedule                 23         United
3-22-2019      Dubai          Airplane land              35         Etihad
```

The code should check if Summary.str.contains('Airplane ') & df.Summary.str.contains('Land') and if City == City and Flight No. == Flight No and Company == Company then return last entire within three days . So if all conditions are true on the 18th and 20th the code should return the 20 only. but if it is true for the 18th and 21th it should keep both. Please note that not all columns with have the same data( not a duplicated rows)

The desired output should look like the dataset below:

```
Date           City             Summary              Flight No.    Company
2-18-2019       NY            Airplane land              23         Delta 
2-19-2019       LA            Airplane Land              7          United
2-20-2019      Dubai          Airplane land              92         Emirates
2-21-2019      London         Airplane land              4          British
2-21-2019       LA            Airplane from NY land      29         Delta
~~~
3-10-2019      London         Airplane land              4          British
3-10-2019      Paris          Airplane Land              78        AirFrance
~~~
3-21-2019      Dubai          Airplane land              92         Etihad
3-22-2019     New Delhi       Airplane Land              9          AirAsia
3-22-2019      Dubai          Airplane land              35         Etihad
```

My code is below but it doesn't work

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
import io
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Airplanes.csv")

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
df = df.astype(str)



count = df.groupby(['City', 'Flight No.'])['No.'].transform('size')



df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df[(df.Summary.str.contains('Airplane ') & df.Summary.str.contains('Land'))]


def filter(grp):
    a = grp.Date + timedelta(days=2)
    return grp[~grp.Date.isin(a)]

df = np.where((df['City'] == df['City']) & (df['Company'] == df['Company']) & (df['Flight No.'] == df['Flight No.']).apply(filter).reset_index(drop=True))


export_excel = df.to_excel(r'C:\MS.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
```

It return the below error

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'Date'
```

Please help me find a what to apply all condition and keep the last True entrie within specific days.

Answer (score 0):

First, the condition you use inside np.where will always be True. And, it is unclear from the rest of the code provided what the columns 'Rig' and 'LinerSize'.
Your use of np.where returns a tuple `(array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64),)` and the conditions inside are always True since we'll always have `df['Rig'] == df['Rig']` etc. A common use of np.where would be to specify in addition a couple of values: one in case of True on your condition and the other in the False case. Yet, this will return a Series, not the full dataframe, to which you are trying to apply the filter function.
I suggest to use the filter like:

```
city_list = ['NY', 'LA'] # just an example
company_list = ['Delta', 'United'] # another example
flight_list = [23, 7, 92] # same

res = df[(df['City'].isin(city_list)) &
            (df['Company'].isin(company_list)) &
            (df['Flight No.'].isin(flight_list))
            ].copy()

# Let's convert the date to datetime so that we subtract dates
res['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(res['Date'])

# Let's ensure that Date is monotonic, increasing
df.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)
# Let's now caluclate the time difference in days with the next flight

res['Next_Flight'] = res['Date'].shift(-1) 
res['Next_Flight'] = (res['Next_Flight'] - res['Date']).dt.days

# Let window be the number of days within which there should not be a next flight
window = 3
# Ensure now that NaNs are filled in 
# with a value that will let them filtered
res['Next_Flight'] = np.where(res['Next_Flight'].isnull(),
                                 window + 1, res['Next_Flight'])
# Filter on the next flight, assuming we will eliminate flights when the 
# next flight is in a window of 3 days

res = res[res['Next_Flight'] > window ]
```

That should help you get closer to what you want

Comment: That wouldn't work. What I need is to remove the duplicated conditions within 3 days so if the same city with the same company appeared after 4 days I should keep both rows.

Comment: If I understand well, whenever there there's a flight within 3 days the first flight should not be selected. This is achieved by back shifting the dates and calculating the number of days difference. I hope this works now.

Comment: Actually this deleted all the rows I have close result with only `df = df[(df.Summary.str.contains('Airplane ') & df.Summary.str.contains('Land'))]` yet I has some duplicated rows every now and then and by duplicated I don't mean the whole row but it means they say the flight landed  when they already wrote that in the summary in a previous day. Also Flight No is not a unique value

Comment: Can provide the filter criteria (City, Company etc...) and print how you'd like the output to be?

Comment: I am filtering the **Summary** column with the keywords the summary has much more than the one in the example that's why I used contains. Every day someone else is entering the log and they can enter the same thing as the previous day. the output is there and you can see in it that id the same criteria are repeated after more than 3 days it should be kept. in the output you can see that rows 4 and 6 are the same but they have more than 3 days difference that is why they are both kept while in the same was for dubai on the 18th and 20th and we kept the 20th only because it's <=3 days

Comment: I reviewed the filter and put it in a function. It gives the outputs above. Is that what you are looking for?